# Get the element name attribute in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I get the element `name` attribute in JavaScript?

*HTML :*

```
<input class="so" name="Name" value="bob"></input>
<input class="so" name="LastName" value="Feyzi"></input>
<input class="so" name="Email"></input>
<input class="so" name="Address"></input>
<input type="submit"></input>
```

*JavaScript :*

```
var person={};
var cars = document.querySelectorAll(".so");
for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) { 
  var elname = document.getElementByClassName('.so')[i].getAttribute('name');
  //var eln = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].getAttribute("name");
  var vala = document.querySelectorAll('.so')[i].value;
  //alert(vala);
  alert(elname);
}
```

After I run the script I want the `person` *object* to be set with this data:

```
person {
    Name: "bob",
    LastName: "Feyzi",
    Email: "",
    Adderss: ""
}
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/guyavunf/1/)

Comment: Plural. `getElementsByClassName` not `getElementByClassName`.

Comment: Why use document.getElementsByTagName("input") while you could use `cars` as reference in your for lus? E.g. `cars[i].value`

Comment: Also, you are not supposed to have `.so`, rather `so`. You have already specified that you are looking for a class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the collection that you've already found with `querySelectorAll` to get the values of the `value` and `name` attributes :

```
var person = {}
var cars = document.querySelectorAll(".so")
for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) { 
  person[cars[i].name] = cars[i].value
}
console.log(person)
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/guyavunf/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Because getElementByClassName does not exist (also it would have no use in your script). Use this:

```
 var person={};
 var cars = document.querySelectorAll(".so");
 for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) { 
       alert(cars[i].name)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, use `cars` variable instead of calling `querySelectorAll` every time.
Secondly, use addEventListener to execute code on click.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/guyavunf/3/

Code:

```
// HTML
<input class="so" name="Name" value="bob"></input>
<input class="so" name="LastName" value="Feyzi"></input>
<input class="so" name="Email"></input>
<input class="so" name="Address"></input>
<input class="submit" type="submit"></input>

// JS
document.querySelector('.submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var person={};
    var cars = document.querySelectorAll(".so");
    for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) { 
        var name = cars[i].name;
        var value = cars[i].value;
        alert(name + ': ' + value);
    }
});
```